# Spark Dataframe Window lag function based on multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((201601, 100.5),
  (201602, 120.6),
  (201603, 450.2),
  (201604, 200.7),
  (201605, 121.4))).toDF("date", "volume")

val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("date")    
val leadDf = df.withColumn("new_col", lag("volume", 1, 0).over(w))
leadDf.show()

+------+------+-------+
|  date|volume|new_col|
+------+------+-------+
|201601| 100.5|    0.0|
|201602| 120.6|  100.5|
|201603| 450.2|  120.6|
|201604| 200.7|  450.2|
|201605| 121.4|  200.7|
+------+------+-------+
```

This is working fine.

But if I have one more column as territory like below.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((201601, ter1, 10.1),
  (201601, ter2, 10.6),
  (201602, ter1, 10.7),
  (201603, ter3, 10.8),
  (201603, ter4, 10.8),
  (201603, ter3, 10.8),
  (201604, ter4, 10.9))).toDF("date", "territory", "volume")
```

My requirement is for the same territory, I want to find the volume of previous month(if exists) if not exists just assign a value 0.0

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: I tried doing this way..

Comment: `val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("date", "territory")

val leadDf = df.withColumn("new_col", lag("volume", 1, 0).over(w))`  But doesnt work

Comment: I just included territory in orderBy clause....doesnt give the correct results

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6.2, Scala 2.10

Comment: Can any one pls let me know how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the value of the previous date for the same territory.

If so then just add partitionBy i.e. redefine your window spec as follows:

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("territory").orderBy("date")
```